# Want to convert an XML String into a JMS message object

Tags: java, xml, jms, data-conversion

I have XML in the form of text, and I want to convert it into a JMS message object for testing purposes. I can't seem to find the exact method or way to do that.

Comment: Please share the methods you tried by pasting the code here.

Comment: This was just a general query. 
I used the `TextMessage message = new TextMessageImpl();`

`message.setText(string);`

Answer (score 0):

There are several implementations of [`javax.jms.Message`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html). If you are using a `String` then the simplest implementation to use would be [`java.jms.TextMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html). You can use the [`createTextMessage(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createTextMessage-java.lang.String-) method on your instance of `javax.jms.Session` to create the message containing your XML `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Well This is how I got my code to work

```
TextMessage message = new TextMessageImpl();
message.setText(xmlString);
```

Comment: You should be using the JMS API to create your `javax.jms.TextMessage` instance rather than instantiating it directly via `TextMessageImpl()`. If you use implementation objects like `TextMessageImpl` this will reduce the portability of your code. You can use the `createTextMessage(String)` method on your instance of `javax.jms.Session` to create the message containing your XML `String` as noted in my answer.